# How to make composer packages global

Tags: composer-php

After creating a few duplicate snipe it installations I think it's better to move installed composer packages to a global location (so I won't have to download/install them each time I create a new snipe it instance). How and where should I put these ? Already moved composer to /usr/local/bin . Ultimate goal is to remove the packages from the vendor subfolders and load them from global location. What would need to be changed in the snipe it folders ?
Thanks

Running Ubuntu server 20.04

What I did was:

1. copy site1 to site2
2. create db for site2
3. add extra ip in apache ports.conf to listen on
4. add ip in netplan yaml file
5. create new ssl key for extra ip
6. created conf for site2 in sites-available + a2ensite
7. modified .env for url app key en db settings

My main problem is that php artisan key:generate throws an error when in root of site2. Was able to generate app key with echo "base64:$(openssl rand -base64 32)" and site2 works as it shoulds for now.

Comment: Could I just copy the contents of the vendor subfolder to /var/www/vendor and then in the project folders' composer.json add 
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "/var/www/vendor"
},

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to reduce space used by composer packages and let all the different instances of snipe it use the same folder with composer modules. Is the composer.json file just to select what modules have to be installed for the project to work or does this also apply after modules have been installed. I want to be sure it all still works if I remove the vendor folder in all the snipe it directories...